# Are pieces for orchestra written mainly by pianists and keyboard players?

Tags: piano, composition, synthesizer, orchestra

I'm just wondering if pieces for orchestra are/were mainly written on pianos or synthesizers. Is it just written on piano for all the instruments since on the piano it's easiest to play both harmony/melody?

(Even though the piano might not even be used in the actual performance?)

Comment: It's easier to write music with a pencil than a piano. Your arms soon get tired trying to hold the piano and make marks on music paper with it.

Comment: I won't let anyone write on my pianos. It's hell to polish out...

Comment: Orchestras are never written. *Orchestrations, symphonies, concertos*, well, that's different.

Comment: A lot of jazz, rock and blues pieces are composed on guitar. It depends on whether the underlying compositional structure is chord-based or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, composers/orchestrators have generally found keyboard a more useful tool than guitar (though I'm sure we could find a few exceptions).

The future may see more and more composers writing directly into a computer though.  One man with a keyboard can try out more than one man with a guitar.  One man with a sequencer can try out more than either!

Comment: As I'm not classically trained, I have never written any orchestral piece on anything other than sequencer. if I need it scoring, I get someone else to do that later ;)

Comment: "I'm sure we could find a few exceptions" - Two notable exceptions were Chopin (yes, really!!) and Berlioz

Comment: @alephzero Wow, did I understand that correctly? They composed on guitar instead of on piano?!

Comment: @Richard, Chopin composed on the violin and Berlioz - on guitar, as far as I remember.

Comment: What Chopin *composed* on, I don't know, but he certainly once said "Nothing is more beautiful than a guitar, save perhaps two" - and he played the instrument himself. AFAIK Berlioz was *not* a keyboard player - not a competent one, anyway - but he supplemented his income by *teaching* the guitar.